# Как сделать фильтрацию "не равно" в выборке Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть модель:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    begin = models.IntegerField('Year begin', null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.IntegerField('Year end', null=True, blank=True)
```

Надо сделать выборку из базы по условию: begin != end + 2
Пытаюсь делать так:

```
objects = Object.objects.filter(begin__gte=0).filter(end__gte=0).filter(~Q(begin=F('end')+2))
```

Но в выборку попадают объекты у которых begin == end + 2.
Например begin = 2020 и end = 2022.
Что делаю не так? Как решить проблему?

PS. Пробовал так же:

```
objects = Object.objects.filter(begin__gte=0, end__gte=0).exclude(Q(begin=F('end')+2))
```

и

```
objects = Object.objects.filter(Q(begin__gte=0) & Q(end__gte=0) & ~Q(begin=F('end')+2))
```

Результат тот же.

Comment: `.exclude(begin=F('end')+2)`

Comment: Тот же самый результат

Answer (score 0):

Сработало такое решение:

```
objects = Object.objects.annotate(delta=F('end') - F('begin')).exclude(delta=2)
```